# EF 4.1 Code First Initialize my database

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework-4

I'am using EF code first to buil my project.
I use seed method to initialize data in my database, but only some class model data have been register in the database.
I dont have any warning or problem.
for exemple: 
1) Does not

```
var categories = new List<Categorie>{ 
                new Categorie{Nom="Informatique"}, 
                new Categorie{Nom="Bien Etre"}, 
 };
            categories.ForEach(s => context.Categories.Add(s));
            context.SaveChanges();
```

Class model:

```
public class Categorie 
    { 
        public int CategorieID { get; set; }
        public string Nom { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Cour> Cours { get; set; }
    }
```

2) Done

```
var coachs = new List<Coach>
            { 
new Coach{Nom="Guith",Prenom="Etienne", Login="etienneguith",Password="etienneguith",Profession="Neurologue",Cour="Medecine generale",Email="guithetienne@mic.be",agenda=temp1},
new Coach{Nom="John",Prenom="Robert", Login="robertjohn",Password="robertjohn",Profession="Juge",Cour="Droit Penal",Email="robertjohn@mic.be",agenda=temp2}, 
 };
        categories.ForEach(s => context.Categories.Add(s));
        context.SaveChanges();
```

Class Model

```
public class Coach
    {
        public int CoachID { get; set; }
        public string Nom { get; set; }
        public string Prenom { get; set; }
        public string Login { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string Profession { get; set; }
        public string Cour { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public DateTime agenda { get; set; }


        public virtual ICollection<Session> Sessions { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: Is the `Coach` collection not getting written to the database?

Comment: Can you share the code that performs the seeding?

Comment: I assume this code is from the `Seed()` method of an `IDatabaseInitializer` implementation. Can you post the rest of the implementation, as well as the code that sets the database initializer?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you are unintentionally iterating the **categories** collection twice.

```
var coachs = new List<Coach>
{ 
    new Coach{Nom="Guith",Prenom="Etienne", Login="etienneguith",Password="etienneguith",Profession="Neurologue",Cour="Medecine generale",Email="guithetienne@mic.be",agenda=temp1},
    new Coach{Nom="John",Prenom="Robert", Login="robertjohn",Password="robertjohn",Profession="Juge",Cour="Droit Penal",Email="robertjohn@mic.be",agenda=temp2}, 
};

categories.ForEach(s => context.Categories.Add(s));
context.SaveChanges();
```

Looks like it should be:

```
var coachs = new List<Coach>
{ 
    new Coach{Nom="Guith",Prenom="Etienne", Login="etienneguith",Password="etienneguith",Profession="Neurologue",Cour="Medecine generale",Email="guithetienne@mic.be",agenda=temp1},
    new Coach{Nom="John",Prenom="Robert", Login="robertjohn",Password="robertjohn",Profession="Juge",Cour="Droit Penal",Email="robertjohn@mic.be",agenda=temp2}, 
};

coachs.ForEach(s => context.Coachs.Add(s));
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Sorry, it's only a mistake when I post my question, I paste the same code.On my project It's normaly like you changes, but it doesn't Work